# Biblatex: endash instead of hyphen in page ranges

Tags: biblatex

> Quick PSA for people like me, who might end up here via Google in the
>   future: This issue **has generally resolved itself with
>   Biblatex Version 3.11** - if you have this installed, you might be
>   having a different problem. (As by the comments of Ulrike Fischer &
>   Moewe)
>
> If you have Biblatex 3.11 and it is still not working, that might be due to the line "\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}" which seems to reset it.

---

If I quote a span of pages of a work, the dash should not be a hyphen. In the Bibliography, Bib**la**tex correctly changes anything into an endash. The footnotes, however, only have a hyphen. If I input it with "--", there are some issues with the recognition as a page range, resulting in repeat longer citations instead of ibidems (and its rather 'unclean' to just manually type a dash anytime Tex should be doing something it can clearly do for the Bibliography).

[image: Problem]

I found two solutions that didn't work:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{\renewcommand*{\bibrangedash}{\textendash}}
```

and

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{\protected\def\bibrangedash{\textendash}}
```

Could someone please help me change this minor thing? Thanks a million in advance!

MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-inote,
backref=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\bibi.bib}
@article{dash,
  author = {Dashing, Walter Very},
  year = {1942},
  title = {Dashing Past a Hyphen},
  journaltitle = {Life},
  volume = {42},
  number = {42},
  pages = {123-321},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\bibi.bib}

\begin{document}

Could I get a dash please -- size does matter in typography...\footcite[142-242]{dash}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will happen in biblatex 3.11, you can get the development version from sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am a bit hesitant meddling with the "internals", but good to know that a workaround might not be needed indefinitely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As of biblatex's version 3.11, the page ranges in the `postonote` are normalized by default, so that hyphens and dashes in page ranges will be transformed to `\bibrangedash`, and commas and semi-colons to `\bibrangesep`. For more details, see the release notes for version 3.11. In other words, the answer below is outdated and no longer needed. Unless you are stuck with an outdated version of biblatex for some reason.

If you don't want to use the development version, as suggested by Ulrike Fischer, you can change the formatting directives of the postnote with:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
```

Technically, that would compact the `postnote` page ranges, but if you don't want that, you can set the counters used by `\mkcomprange` so that it doesn't actually happen.

Note that the version 3.11 should arrive soon to distribution, as reported by @moewe in the comments. And it will handle your issue out of the box. So, with a bit of patience, you shoudn't need to do anything at all.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=verbose-inote,
backref=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dash,
  author = {Dashing, Walter Very},
  year = {1942},
  title = {Dashing Past a Hyphen},
  journaltitle = {Life},
  volume = {42},
  number = {42},
  pages = {123-321},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\setcounter{mincomprange}{100000}
\setcounter{mincompwidth}{100000}

\begin{document}

Could I get a dash please -- size does matter in typography...\footcite[142-242]{dash}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know what "compacting the page ranges" means, but as long as it works, I'm happy. :)

Comment: Compacting the page ranges is that, when you have a range `123-134` and it is rendered, e.g., as `123-34`. `biblatex` does that for you, but I assumed you were not previously using this feature, so the counters are set not to do this for page numbers smaller than six digits.

Comment: Now I get it - thanks! That would indeed have been my next question, I assume..

Comment: Please be sure to update your answer once 3.11 is released (might take another week or two). It is a bit frustrating to see people use unnecessary/clumsy code from answers that have become outdated.

Comment: @moewe, I didn't know the new version was due soon, and the answer does recognize this will not be needed when the new version arrives. But the request is fair enough: will be done.

Comment: Thank you. 'the development version' is not specific about the final release version in which this will not be necessary. In my experience people don't necessarily read that bit of the answer thoroughly, so I try to make it very explicit if code is only needed for older versions.

Comment: @moewe, explicit it is then. :)

Comment: Thanks. Though we may have to see how soon 'soon' really is...

Comment: I put it into the question as well, since non-programming people like me tend to try inserting various scavenged bits of code into their header before reading all the comments...

Comment: @PaulBurgh, that was precisely the reason for moewe's request. In which s/he is correct. We thank you for the questions's update.

Comment: I have a follow-up: I got rid of the "p." before pagenumbers by the always-suggested method of "\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}". However, that seems to break the dash-replacement-mechanism of Biblatex 3.11. Is there another way to get rid of "p." while retaining the hyphen-to-dash-replacement?

Comment: @PaulBurgh Try `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}`.

Comment: @gusbrs perfect, that did it! Cheers!